# Chamar classe progress bar de outro arquivo

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

Pessoal venho pedir ajuda de vcs, acredito que muito simples mas que da uma dor de cabeça danada pra quem não tem muita pratica com orientação a objeto, eu tenho um arquivo `progressbar.py`, que como o nome ja é auto explicativo,contem uma progressbar em pyqt4, quero chamar a classe do arquivo passando como parametro um título, algo como:

```
 from modules import progressbar 

 progressbar.ProgressBar("TITULO AQUI")
```

OBS: Como é um bar de atividade não me preocupo em passar a % de progresso, simplesmente vou deixar ela ativa enquanto um determinado processo estiver sendo executado,
Aguardando anciosamente um feedback de vcs

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import time
import sys
import qdarkstyle

class ProgressBar(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self,title):
        super(ProgressBar, self).__init__()
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.title = title

        label = QtGui.QLabel()

        label.setText(self.title)
        label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(label)
        # Create a progress bar and a button and add them to the main layout
        self.progressBar = QtGui.QProgressBar(self)
        self.progressBar.setRange(0,1)
        layout.addWidget(self.progressBar)

        self.myLongTask = TaskThread()
        self.myLongTask.taskFinished.connect(self.onFinished)
        self.onStart()

    def onStart(self):
        self.progressBar.setRange(0,0)
        self.myLongTask.start()

    def onFinished(self):
        # Stop the pulsation
        self.progressBar.setRange(0,1)


class TaskThread(QtCore.QThread):
    taskFinished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(30)
        self.taskFinished.emit()
```

Na minha Função Principal `main.py` a parte que chamo progressbar é exatamente esta :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys, time
from PyQt4.QtGui import  QMessageBox, QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt4.uic import loadUi
import qdarkstyle

from .modules import tricks
from .modules import progressbar 


    class PyAuto(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super(PyAuto, self).__init__()

            # instances
            self.ui = loadUi('Pyauto/views/menu.ui', self)
            self.ui.test.clicked.connect(self.test_progressbar)
            self.ui.show()

        def test_progressbar(self):

            window = progressbar.ProgressBar("Test")
            window.show()
            app.exec_()



    if __name__ == '__main__':

        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        app.setStyleSheet(qdarkstyle.load_stylesheet(pyside=False))   # set stylesheet dark
        myWindow = PyAuto()
        app.exec_()
```

Comment: Bom, você simplesmente não compartilhou o código mais importante, que é o construtor da classe `ProgressBar`. :) De todas as formas, basta vc adicionar o parâmetro no construtor (função `__init__`), **da mesma forma que você já faz** na sua classe `MyCustomWidget` com a variável `title`. (isso se eu realmente entendi a sua dificuldade, porque a pergunta não tá muito clara...)

Comment: Olá amigo, coloquei o código,  nessa test progressbar vou fazer algo como

enquanto o processo("teste") existir:

          rodeprogressbar("processo teste rodando, aguarde")


aguardando feedback, obrigado.

Comment: Ah, a sua classe `ProgressBar` na verdade se chama `MyCustomWidget`! Eu não havia entendido porque você literalmente chama ela de `ProgressBar` num exemplo lá no começo. Tá, mas aí eu não entendi o seu problema/dificuldade. Vc já está passando um "título" (`"Test"`) na chamada do construtor, e lá dentro você já está usando ele num no `label`. Qual é o problema?

Comment: o problema, é que se eu chamo o arquivo sozinho, ele funciona, quando eu chamo de outra classe a progressbar, abre e se fecha no mesmo instante.

Comment: P.S.: Não deixe de corrige o nome da classe na pergunta (troque `Progressbar("TITULO AQUI")` por `MyCustomWidget("TITULO AQUI")`). Senão pode continuar confundindo outras pessoas. :)

Comment: talvez falte algo em 

`window.show()`
  `app.exec()`

Comment: `window.show()` só exibe o componente gráfico. Você *sempre* precisa ter um `app.exec()` (um só, no código principal) pra permitir o Qt manter o loop principal da aplicação. Se não ele exibe e termina mesmo.

Comment: troquei os nomes

Comment: @LuizVieira mas o app.exec_() está no código, mesmo assim nao roda, da o seguinte erro: `QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running`

Comment: Sim, eu testei e vi o erro (não tinha a ver com a falta de `exec`). Respondi e espero que ajude. No futuro, tente preparar um [mcve] que reproduza o erro. Fica muito mais fácil de que alguém se interesse em te ajudar. :) Boa sorte!

Comment: @LuizVieira, muito Obrigado, vou verificar seu exemplo agora, essa é minha primeira dúvida postada no stack, vou seguir como vc disse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você cria (instancia) o seu objeto da classe `ProgressBar` dentro do *slot* do clique do botão (dentro da chamada de `test_progressbar`). Assim, o escopo dessa variável é só aquela função (isto é, ela só existe enquanto a função existir). Assim que a função termina, o objeto é deletado e por isso você enxerga ele aparecer e sumir.

O ideal é ter essa instância numa propriedade da sua classe principal (`PyAuto`). Por exemplo:

```
def __init__(self):
    super(PyAuto, self).__init__()

    # instances
    self.window = progress.ProgressBar("Test") # <==== Adição
    . . .
```

E depois, no clique do botão, controlar a exibição da classe já existente:

```
def test_progressbar(self):
    if not self.window.isVisible():
        self.window.show()
    else:
        self.window.hide()
```

Se mesmo assim você preferir instanciar uma nova classe a cada clique no botão, garanta que a referência dela seja armazenada na classe principal. Algo do tipo:

```
def __init__(self):
    super(PyAuto, self).__init__()

    # instances
    self.window = None
```

E então:

```
def test_progressbar(self):
    self.window = progressbar.ProgressBar("Test")
    self.window.show()
```

E não precisa de `exec`, pois a chamada já está sendo feita na função principal.